# Should I use model.eval() when using transformers.pipeline for inference with a fine-tuned BERT model in PyTorch?

Tags: python, machine-learning, pytorch, nlp, huggingface-transformers

When training transformer models with `Trainer()`, documentation shows the following usage:

```py
model = AutoModelForSequenceClassification.from_pretrained("bert-base-cased", num_labels=5)

trainer = Trainer(
    model=model,
    args=training_args,
    train_dataset=small_train_dataset,
    eval_dataset=small_eval_dataset,
    compute_metrics=compute_metrics,
)
```

If you check `model.training` flag, it's set to `false` by default, but `Trainer` has a logic which calls `model.train()` to set it to `True`, which makes sense.

When using this fine-tuned model for inference, you can leverage `transformers.pipeline`, which accepts model object as an argument. But, `pipeline` doesn't have a logic to check if model is in training mode. I haven't found it in source code, and I don't see it anywhere in the documentation. When I use `pipeline` for predictions, results are not deterministic, which is another indicator that model is not in eval mode.

```
generator = pipeline(
                "some_task",
                model=model,
                tokenizer=tokenizer,
                aggregation_strategy=aggregation_strategy,
                ignore_labels=[],
            )

generator("Example")    # returns score X
generator("Example")    # returns score Y

# but if model.eval() is used before creating pipeline object
generator("Example")    # returns score X
generator("Example")    # returns score X
```

Should I call `model.eval()` before using the model in `pipeline` or should `pipeline` handle it by itself but because of some reason it doesn't?

Comment: I assume `model` is a pytorch model instance and not a string? -> in this case you explicitly need to call `.eval()`.

Comment: Yes, it's a pytorch model.